# What permissions does a user need to run `git ls-remote`?

Tags: linux, permissions, git

I have a Git repository within my home folder on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.  A system utility user 'gremlin' needs to check that this is a real Git repository.  The best way to do that that I've found is with the `git ls-remote` command, a la

```bash
$ git ls-remote -h /home/me/path/to/repo.git &> /dev/null ; echo $?
```

which (in ideal cases) returns an exit code of 0 if the directory is a Git repository and something else (usually 128) if it's not.

The problem is that when 'gremlin' runs this command for a valid repo,

```bash
$ sudo -u gremlin git ls-remote -h /home/me/path/to/repo.git &> /dev/null ; echo $?
```

the exit code is `128`, indicating the repo is not valid.  I get `0` when I run it as myself.

I assume the problem is a permissions issue, but I can't tell what the issue is.  I don't know how `git ls-remote` works exactly, but my best guess is that it reads from the target repo's `.git/refs/remotes/`.  I have confirmed that the entire filepath of `.git/refs/remotes/`, from `/` all the way down to the contents within it, have `r` permissions for the "other" user (equivalent to `$ sudo chmod -R o+r /` for the fileset in question), so 'gremlin' ought to be able to read from this folder with no problem.

The issue is obviously more complex, but I don't know where to start.  Ideally, someone here knows enough about how `git ls-remote` works to know what permissions a user needs to execute it.

Comment: Check your directory permissions. Keep in mind that reading a directory is optional. Traversing (+x) is not.

Comment: I did forget that!  My home directory was missing `o+x`.  Fixing that made it work, thanks!

Comment: @DanielB: This merits an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A system utility user 'gremlin' needs to check that this is a real Git repository

The various options of `git rev-parse` might also be suitable for that if you're looking to check whether it's a bare repository specifically, or whether it has a working tree, etc.

```
git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/me/path/to/repo.git
git --git-dir=/home/me/path/to/repo.git rev-parse --git-dir
git --git-dir=/home/me/path/to/repo.git rev-parse HEAD
```

> I can't tell what the issue is

Use the `strace` command to see the specific system calls that a process makes. If you expect it to be a file permission issue, look for the ones which fail with `EACCES` [sic].

```
strace -f git ls-remote /home/me/path/to/repo.git
```

> my best guess is that it reads from the target repo's .git/refs/remotes/

It reads the entire `.git/refs/` (plus `.git/packed-refs`, but the 'refs' directory must still exist even if all refs are packed). It is not looking for nested remotes within that remote. There are other files it needs, at minimum I believe `.git/config` and `.git/HEAD`, plus the presence of an object store at `.git/objects/`.

> have r permissions for the "other" user (equivalent to $ sudo chmod -R o+r / for the fileset in question), so 'gremlin' ought to be able to read from this folder with no problem.

*Reading* the folder is not enough. You also need permissions to *traverse* it in order to access any object inside (i.e. do anything beyond getting a list of filenames), which re-uses the `+x` permission bit. For example, in order to access `.git/refs/` in any way, the user must have `+x` on the parent `.git` directory.

Use `namei -l <absolute_path>` to check the permissions all the way up.

Comment: Beautiful answer, and the `strace` idea is brilliant.